# Python: given a list of lists, create a list ordered by the number of occurrences in inner list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
[['a','b','c'], ['a'], ['a','b']]
```

I want to sort it and return a single list so the output looks like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

i.e. ordered by the number of times each element appears. a appears 3 times, b appears twice, and c appears once.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: A shot in the dark but maybe create a `collections.Counter` object and use `sorted` with `most_common()[1]` as the key.

Comment: thank you all for the comments. I understand how this works now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a'], ['a', 'b']]

d = Counter(chain.from_iterable(data))
print([i for i, c in d.most_common()])
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

<sub>Note: When you want to count the frequence of some items in a list, remember to use `Counter`, it's really helpful.</sub>

Comment: Why use `chain.from_iterable(data)` vs `chain(*data)`?

Comment: @dansalmo: I'd say it's because "There should be one obvious way to do it". And I think `chain.from_iterable` is the standard way of doing it.

Comment: @Haidro: Yeah they're pretty much the same. That's why I upvoted yours ;)

Comment: @Haidro: Yes, I saw that after I put up mine and then actually changed it to show your [0] referencing.  I did do my own tinkering with dir() to find the .most_common method not realizing it was in many answers of this thread already.  I also like `zip(*c.most_common())[0]` in @DSM's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` to first flatten the list, then [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the elements.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [x[0] for x in Counter(chain.from_iterable(mylist)).most_common())
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: This won't work as written -- you have no guarantee that the results will be ordered as the OP wants.

Comment: try: zip(*Counter(chain*(mylist)).most_common())[0]

Answer (score 4):

`collections.Counter` should do it:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lol = [['a','b','c'], ['a'], ['a','b']]
>>> c = Counter(elem for sublist in lol for elem in sublist)
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

The `elem for sublist..` bit is simply a flattening idiom.  You could use

```
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(lol))
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

instead, after `from itertools import chain`.  Then you can get the most common:

```
>>> c.most_common()
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

and then extract the keys however you like:

```
>>> [x[0] for x in c.most_common()]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> zip(*c.most_common())[0]
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
LoL= [['a','b','c'], ['a'], ['a','b']]     

d={}
for e in [i for sub in LoL for i in sub]:
    d[e]=d.setdefault(e,0)+1

print sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to keep a counter for each element inside each sublist. Something like this,

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [['a','b','c'], ['a'], ['a','b']]
>>> counts = Counter()
>>> for sublst in lst:
...     for ele in sublst:
...         counts[ele] += 1
... 
>>> [ele for ele, _ in counts.most_common()]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
import operator
mlist= [['a','b','c'], ['a'], ['a','b']]
elist= [x for x,y in sorted(
    Counter([l for s in mlist for l in s]).iteritems(),
    key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)]
print elist
```